# Get unread count in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, notifications, sms, counter

Is it possible in Windows Phone 8 to add a functionality in my app, which counts the number of unread notifications such as SMS, EMAIL, VOICE MESSAGES or MISSED CALLS.

I know this can be achieved in Android, but wondering the same can be done in Windows Phone 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do from your application in the public API.

You can create SMS, E-mail, calls, etc But can't get access to a list of SMS, e-mails, calls on the device.

It is an element of information security.